# Should I use both client side and external connection pooling together?

Tags: database, database-connection, connection-pooling

- client side pooling: I mean pooling from the application library
- middleware pooling: I mean something like PgBouncer

I know this question definitely depends on the workload but I still hope to have some options about pros and cons here.